# PHP Splitting a result

Tags: php, split, flip

I was hoping to get some ideas/help with php. 

 I use the following to return a value which in my case is **612B** Hex decimal. I need to flip the 61 & 2B and make 2B61.

```
$skillsearch1 = odbc_exec($conn1,"select cast(cast(reverse(substring(strevent, 1, 1))as varbinary)as int) from USER_EVENT where strUserID='loneranger'");
$skillfound1 = odbc_result($skillsearch1,1);
```

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

where

```
 str_split($test, 2)));
```

I just had to change it to

```
 str_split($test, 1)));
```

And I got exactly what I wanted. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it is a string - `$skillfound1 = substr($skillfound1, 2) . substr($skillfound1, 0, 2);` or `$skillfound1 = preg_replace('/(\w{2})(\w{2})/', '$2$1', $skillfound1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$test = '1234';

$result = implode(                     // 3. join array to string
            array_reverse(             // 2. reverse order of this array
                str_split($test, 2))); // 1. convert string to array with two chars values

var_dump($result);
```